# mysql - select random rows with max 3 rows per parent id

Tags: mysql, subquery, random

I currently have a query that returns a maximum of 3 rows per parent_id. I want to enhance the query to return a maximum of 3 random rows per parent_id. This does not work for me at the moment as it returns to me Ascending id's each time I try.

```
SELECT id, rest_id, rn
FROM (SELECT (@rn := if(@rest_id = rest_id, @rn + 1,
                    if(@rest_id := rest_id, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as rn,
         meals.*   
  FROM meals CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @rn := 0, @rest_id := '') params
  ORDER BY rand() 
 ) meals
WHERE rn <= 3
order by id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want random rows **per `parent_id`**, your inner ORDER BY should arrange rows in a way that same `parent_id` rows are grouped together. So, instead of

```
ORDER BY rand()
```

it should be

```
ORDER BY parent_id ASC, rand()
```

As for this:

> it returns to me Ascending id's each time I try

The reason your query returns ascending IDs each time is because you have instructed it to return the results in the ascending order of `id` with this line at the end of the query:

```
ORDER BY id ASC
```

So, again, if you want the output to show same `parent_id` rows grouped together, add the `parent_id` column as the first sorting criterion to the final ORDER BY as well:

```
ORDER BY parent_id ASC, id ASC
```